# remove duplicate values from record by removing dropdown value after selection

Tags: dropdown

I have  one dropdown in my form .....

if we click dropdown and it shows vales like 1
                                                             2
     3 
     4  etc

I select value **(1)** in dropdown and saved those values in table successfully.

i need to remove the selected value**(1)** from dropdown after saved those values in table ....

If we click the dropdown again....**I need the below result.....**

I need result like    2
    3
     4

value 1 have to remove from the  dropdown...How?

Comment: how to do this with sql query using joins i have 3 tables employee,aspnetuser,department

Comment: maybe if you provide us some piece of code it would be easier to debug :)